# A better way to get command line outputs with python?

Tags: python, command-line

I want to call the command line from within python, e.g.  command from inside python, e.g.:

```
import os
os.system("git log")
```

and I want to get the output of this command as a list of strings and operate on it in python.  The way I currently do this is, e.g.:

```
import os
os.system("git log > gitlog.txt")
text_file = open("gitlog.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
```

I suspect there is a better way.  Am I right, and if so, what is it?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

proc = Popen(['git', 'log'], stdout=PIPE)
lines = proc.stdout.readlines()
```